# Association between models failing in Ext js 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I am working on small example to understand association which is working fine in Ext js 5 but failing in Ext js 6 version.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

// parent model
Ext.define('Continent', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    field: ['name'],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'Country',
        name: 'countries'
    }
});


//child model
Ext.define('Country', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    field: ['name'],
    associations: [{
        type: 'belongsTo',
        model: 'Continent',
        associationKey: 'countries',
    }]
});

//created store for parent which contains child data
Ext.define('ContinentStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'continent',
    model: 'Continent',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        data: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            countries: [{
                name: 'India'
            }, {
                name: 'Srilanka'
            }, {
                name: 'Bangladesh'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            countries: [{
                name: 'Nigeria'
            }, {
                name: 'Kenya'
            }, {
                name: 'South Africa'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            countries: [{
                name: 'West'
            }, {
                name: 'East'
            }, {
                name: 'South'
            }]
        }]
    }
});

var continentGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Continent Grid',
    store: Ext.create('ContinentStore'),
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    listeners: {
        select: function(cmp, record, index) {
            //record.countries() will return new store.
            // to append new store I have used reconfigure method.
            Ext.getCmp('CountryGrid').reconfigure(record.countries());;
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'name',
        text: 'Continent',
        flex: 1
    }]
});
var countryGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Country  Grid',
    id: 'CountryGrid',
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'name',
        text: 'Country',
        flex: 1
    }]
});
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'hbox',
    autoShow: true,
    items: [continentGrid, countryGrid]
})
//console.log(continent);
```

});

when I try to run the example in Ext js 6 verison getting below error.

> Uncaught Error: hasMany ("Continent") and belongsTo ("Country") should not be used in conjunction to declare a relatextionship. Use only one.(…)

working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ika)

Comment: What is your question? It says to use only one.

Comment: Want to know how to make it work in Ext Js 6 version

Comment: It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Fiddle is working fine for me.